# How much beef broth can I make with 800g (1.75 pounds) of bone marrow bones?

Tags: beef, broth

I got 800 grams of raw bone marrow bones from grocery store. There are 5 bones, cut in about 2 inch lengths. How much beef broth can I make with these bones? Presumably I can't make 15 litres of broth from 800g of bones, but I am also hoping to get more than a litre... What is a reasonable bone to water ratio?

Comment: I closed it as a duplicate of the closest worded question, but I actually think that https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/41191/optimum-bone-to-water-ratio-for-pork-and-beef-stocks has more correct answers.